# XSS - Execute Javascript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-webview, xss

I'm testing XSS vulnerability attacks in Android. For this I've developed a web view, where I load a html file which contains a simple form for entering name and email. The contents of html file are:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="search.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I send the data via *get* to a php file, which echoes whatever is written in the name field. The contents of php file are :

```
<html>
<head>
<title> You searched for: </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo $_GET['name'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, my intention is to write *Javascript* inside the *name* field, so that when I echo it, script is executed. Normal strings passed in name field are echoed successfully, so I know that the php code is actually working.

This works on : Mozilla Firefox.

Doesn't work on : Chrome, Android Emulator, Android real device.

EDIT : I missed the input. I am adding a Javascript in *name* field. So the input can be a simple script such as:

```
<script language="Javascript">alert("Hello");</script>
```

Since I'm not sanitizing the input, I expect the script to execute. You can refer this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/) for more information.

But the output is a blank page with no output, which means script isn't executed.

Any ideas?

*Note: I'm concerned with this not working with emulator/Android device only, so please don't answer for Chrome.*

Comment: Not sure what your question is. What are you passing in? What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: well your question is not clear.

Comment: My answer was for Chrome, but in general, you can verify what is happening with the technique I described. Many modern browsers have reflected XSS prevention techniques, so you can test if you are being hit with the XSS prevention by seeing if regular HTML renders, while javascript gets rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with something other than script tags, like some html such as `<b>hello</b>` and see if it renders as bold. Chrome has an XSS auditor that blocks reflected XSS attacks. Check the console to see if that is the case.

Chrome will have a note in the console that says:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in '<your page>' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

Here's a related article on security.se on it: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53474/is-chrome-completely-secure-against-reflected-xss

I just saw your edit. My answer is for chrome, but I suspect that your android device is employing a similar technique (I don't have one to test with). If you would like to bypass the auditor, you can do something like:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> You searched for: </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         <?php
            echo $_GET['name'];
         ?>
      <script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then you can make a request like ?name=alert(1), and the auditor probably won't block it.

Comment: Hi Gray, thanks for your suggestions. You're right and your suggestions did work in Chrome as well as emulator. I suspect the emulator also has the same mechanism for rejecting Javascript. But for an attacker, server php is unaccessible, so I'd want to know if there's any way to do it without modifying the server file. For the demo purposes, this'd just do fine, but I'd really want a way which can do it using the first way similar as in the link. +1 for the inputs though.

Comment: As an attacker (well, a simulated one), the XSS auditor can be a real pain, but just like a web application firewall, you can't stick security software on top of unsecure code and expect security. There are often ways around the auditor, but it depends on how the code is written. There is no universal bypass (that I know of) and Google would probably pay you a bug bounty if you found one (depending on how severe it is). You could do a demo where you break out of an attribute that is unencoded using quotes; I'm pretty sure the auditor won't catch that.  e.g. `<img src="x" title="{payload}"/>

Comment: and the payload could be something like `x" onload=alert1(); alt="x`

Comment: Hi Gray, can you let me know exact input that I should try. Should it be '<img src="x" title="{x "onload=alert(1); alt="x}"/> ? Sorry but I'm new to Javascript, so I couldn't understand all of it. I've read the description of alt, src, onload, title, but still would appreciate if you could provide me exact input that I should type in the textbox. Thanks again!

Comment: As per your comment, I added an <img> tag inside html, and tried the input you suggested. Code looks something like this - 
Image: <img src="Photo" title="{x" onload=alert(1); alt="x}"/> , but still no luck.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to make it work in chrome first to make sure it's not the XSS auditor. Onload requires a valid src, of course. You could try onerror. The auditor may still catch this, actually... It's designed to try to prevent all reflected XSS. Some contexts are harder to detect than others.

Comment: Well, again you're spot on, onerror works just perfectly. But that's the whole problem, here I've got to modify the html file to insert an alert box to the image. Again for an attacker's perspective, this is not possible to mould the html according to his needs. I do get your point that there are XSS detectors designed to prevent Javascript to execute, but that's what I've got to do, unfortunately. But yeah, I really appreciate your efforts. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what modifications you needed to make to the HTML, but it is often the case that XSS just isn't possible. We consider hitting the XSS prevention of the browser a vulnerability because of the potential for a bypass, and it will likely work in other browsers. Also, keep in mind that reflected XSS generally requires some social engineering to actually do anything useful. I guess part of my problem is that I do not 100% sure I understand the goal of your testing, so I am not sure we are on the same page as far as that goes.

Comment: Hi Gray, I'll let you know the whole thing I've been trying to do. I am preparing benchmarking apps which expose Android security vulnerability, and also demonstrating how they can be exploited. So, here the html is basically the file in my app where an attacker would inject a malicious input, and it would get executed on a php file which is on localhost. So, basically I have the vulnerable code, as well I need to show how it is vulnerable by attacking it. I hope it makes things a bit clear for you.